# PHP session array

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array

how can i store this array into a session and use sessions to move the elements inside the array up/down/left/right diagonally

```
$board = array(A B C D E F G H
    0    array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    1    array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    2    array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    3    array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    4    array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    5    array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    6    array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    7    array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
      );
```

I am trying to store this array into a session

```
$pieces = array(
 //checkers pieces player 1
 "b" => '<img src="bp.png" width="33" height="37" alt="black piece">',
      //Checkers pieces for player2
 "r" => '<img src="rp.png" width="33" height="32" alt="red piece">',
        // Empty Squares
 // Black
 "bs" => '<img src="bs.png" width="30" height="30" alt="black square">',
      // Red
 "rs" => '<img src="rs.png" width="30" height="30" alt="black square">'

 );
          // 'es' represents empty squares
$board = array(  A   B    C   D    E   F    G   H
       0  array('b','rs','b','rs','b','rs','b','rs'),
       1  array('rs','b','rs','b','rs','b','rs','b'),
       2  array('b','rs','b','rs','b','rs','b','rs'),
       3  array('rs','bs','rs','bs','rs','bs','rs','bs'),
       4  array('bs','rs','bs','rs','bs','rs','bs','rs'),
       5  array('r','bs','r','bs','r','bs','r','bs'),
       6  array('bs','r','bs','r','bs','r','bs','r'),
       7  array('r','bs','r','bs','r','bs','r','bs')
);

 function map(&$value, $key, $map) {
    if(array_key_exists($value, $map)) {
  $value = $map[$value];
    }
 }

array_walk_recursive($board, 'map', $pieces);
```

and its going to come out into an 8x8 table board when it prints out

I did `$_SESSION['board'] = $board;` after the array_walk_recursive

and put it into

```
              echo "<table border='1'>\n";
  foreach ($_SESSION['board'] as $row)
    {




    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $piece){
     echo "<td>";
     echo "$piece ";
     echo "</td>\n";




     }

    }

   echo "</tr>\n";
   echo "</table>\n";

  }
```

the user is inputing into this function (FROM input box) F5 - (TO Input) G2 the parses it into coordinates with this function

```
// parses the users input --FROM--  and to where the user wnats to move the piece
// if the user inputs F1 it parses that into (0,0) coordinates
function parseSquare() {
    if (strlen($square) != 2) {
    return FALSE;
    }

    $coords = array(ord('A') - ord($square[0]),
            $square[1] - 1);


    // Perform bounds-checking.
    if ($coords[0] < 0 || $coords[0] > 7 || $coords[1] < 0 || $coords[1] > 7) {
    return FALSE;
    }

    return $coords;
}
$coords = parseSquare($square);
if ($coords === FALSE) {
    // Invalid input, handle this case.
} else {
    $piece = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; // for example
}
```

can i use the function above to move diagonally

```
$_SESSION['board'][[$new_i]-1][[$new_j] + 1] = $_SESSION['board'][$old_i][$old_j];
$_SESSION['board'][$old_i][$old_j] = ...;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `session_start` and afterwards store your variables in `$_SESSION` -- they will be available throughout the session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['board'] = array( ... );
```

Moving elements is just a matter of assigning one value to another, for example:

```
$_SESSION['board'][$new_i][$new_j] = $_SESSION['board'][$old_i][$old_j];
$_SESSION['board'][$old_i][$old_j] = ...;
```

Comment: @hgbso: I don't see any new question there.

Comment: $_SESSION['board'][$new_i -1][$new_j +1] = $_SESSION['board'][$old_i][$old_j];
$_SESSION['board'][$old_i][$old_j] = ...;
can i use this to move diagonally

Comment: @hgbso: You can move from anywhere to anywhere. "Moving" the pieces is just setting the new location and emptying the old location.

Comment: its putting user input into that movement like F5 to G2 I  updated the display of the array

Answer (score 2):

> $_SESSION['myArray'] = $board;

and you can access any element using $_SESSION['myArray'][i][j];

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can store and update an array in session.
use like this :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['youarray'] =$board;
```

and now do updates in $_SESSION['youarray'] array according to your requirement that will be like normal array. but stored in session.

Answer (score 1):

You store it in a session like

```
<?php
session_start();
$board=array('whatever');
$session['board']=$board;
```

As for manipulation, it is just a normal array. You can work with it like any other array.