# How to store information from radio buttons?

Tags: php, html, css, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I want to be able to store information from radio buttons so I can send them to a database. For each result of my query I have 2 radio buttons. One for the home team and one for the away team. I want to be able to figure out what the user picked, compare it to the actual winner of the game, then increment the win/losses accordingly. Right now I think I have most of the logic, but I get a php error that I cant figure out for the life of me. So maybe someone here can help me.

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
 <select name="weekNo">
 <option value="1">week 1</option>
 <option value="2">week 2</option>
 <option value="3">week 3</option>
 <option value="4">week 4</option>
 <option value="5">week 5</option>
 <option value="6">week 6</option>
 <option value="7">week 7</option>
 <option value="8">week 8</option>
 <option value="9">week 9</option>
 <option value="10">week 10</option>
 <option value="11">week 11</option>
 <option value="12">week 12</option>
 <option value="13">week 13</option>
 <option value="14">week 14</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Games" />
 </form>
 <br>
 <hr>
 <?php

  $conn = pg_connect("")
  or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //submit button pressed
{
$query=NULL; //prevent compile error

$weekNum = $_POST['weekNo'];

    $query = "SELECT a.game_no AS \"Game Number\", a.home AS \"Home Team\",
            homeTeam.wins AS \"Home Wins\", homeTeam.losses AS \"Home Losses\",
            a.away AS \"Away Team\", awayTeam.wins AS \"Away Wins\",
            awayTeam.losses AS \"Away Losses\", a.spread AS \"Spread\"
            FROM weekly_stats AS a
            INNER JOIN team AS homeTeam ON a.home = homeTeam.name
            INNER JOIN team AS awayTeam ON a.away = awayTeam.name
            WHERE a.week_no = $weekNum";

    $result = pg_query($query) or die ('Query failed: ' .pg_last_error());
    // Printing results in HTML
 echo "<br>There are " . pg_num_rows($result) . " games for this week.\n<p></p>\n";
 echo "<table border=1>\n\t<tr>\n";

 for($i=0; $i<pg_num_fields($result); $i++)
 {
  echo "\t\t<th>" . pg_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>\n";
 }
 echo "\t\t<th>Picks</th>\n";

 echo "\t</tr>\n";

 $row=0;
 $teammnames = array(
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
 "home", "away",
  "home", "away");
  $flag = 0;

  while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))
  {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    $teamnames[$flag] = $line["Home Team"];
    $flag++;
    $teamnames[$flag] = $line["Away Team"];
    $flag++;

    foreach ($line as $col_value)
    {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }

  echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks[$row]\" value=\"home\">Home
 <input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks[$row]\" value=\"away\">Away</td>";


 echo "\t</tr>\n";
 $row++;
 }
    echo "</table>\n";
 echo"<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit2\" value=\"submit2\"></td>";

 echo "</form>";



    if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
            $flag = 0;
            $row = 0;

            for($row=0;$row<pg_num_rows($result);$row++){

                    if($_POST['picks[$row]'] = "home")
                    {
                    $pick = $teamnames[$flag];
                    $flag+=2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $flag++;
                    $pick = $teamnames[$flag];
                    $flag++;
                    }

            pg_prepare($conn, "myquery", 'INSERT INTO $1.user_picks VALUES ($2,$3,$4,$5)');
            pg_execute($conn, "myquery", array_SESSION['league'],$_SESSION['username'],$week_no, $game_no, $pick);
    }
    }

// Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);
}

// Closing connection
pg_close($conn);

?>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the error I get. It is on the pg_execute line

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in    
dg.php on line 219
```

And line 219 is:

```
pg_execute($conn,"myquery",array_SESSION['league'],$_SESSION['username'],
            $week_no,$game_no, $pick);
```

Comment: Line 219 = (what) exactly?

Comment: I am not counting to 219! Which line is that?

Comment: pg_execute($conn, "myquery", array_SESSION['league'],$_SESSION['username'],$week_no, $game_no, $pick);

Comment: For all we know, there could be 50 more lines above what you posted.

Comment: `array_SESSION['league']` try `$_SESSION['league']` or pre-define it as an array - IF - it's part of an array. Also make sure `session_start();` is indeed loaded.

Comment: What you posed does not even contain that line. How are we meant to help?

Comment: @fred -ii- it is part of an array I believe. So how would I pre-define it?

Comment: @arkascha I have an error with my pg_execute statement

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4301203/

Comment: @Fred-ii- Don't I do that at the top with $teamnames?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the array you are passing to the `pg_execute()` correctly.

Try

```
pg_execute($conn, 
           "myquery", 
           array( $_SESSION['league'],
                  $_SESSION['username'],
                  $week_no, 
                  $game_no, 
                  $pick)
          );
```