# How I can insert another value in a array[]?

Tags: php, arrays, opencart

Working with opencart and am trying to enter another value within the product session. By default it only brings ID. How can I get further information?

```
if (!in_array($this->request->post['product_id'], $this->session->data['wishlist'])) {
    $this->session->data['wishlist'][] = $this->request->post['product_id'];
    $this->session->data['wishlist'][] = $my_var;
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear, but my just random guess is `$this->session->data['wishlist'][$this->request->post['product_id']]['my_var_name']= $my_var;`

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly you are trying to add additional data to an already existing array...what you are looking for is

```
array_push();
```

array_push — Push one or more elements onto the end of array

syntax:

```
int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] )
```

example:

```
$array = array();
$addingthistoarray = "value to add";
array_push($array, $addingthistoarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but you should be able to do something like this (assuming your "$_SESSION"):

[PHP session array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301203/php-session-array)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['wishlist'] = array( ... );
...
$_SESSION['wishlist']['product_id'] = $this->request->post['product_id'];
...
```