# PHP Code fails when adding to array (survey)

Tags: php

I need to be able to add to my $questions array, but there is no dynamics in the code, so when I add something I have to create a if sentence and a new input field for each question to store the data (the teacher demands storing in hidden type). Does anyone know a good tip of how I can get it more efficient?

```
<?php 




    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');

    $questions = array(
        array(
            'text' => 'Whats your name?',
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'svar1'
        ),
        array(
            'text' => 'Do you live in Oslo?',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'name' => 'checkbox'
        ),
        array(
            'text' => 'How old are you?',
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'svar3'
        ),
        array(
            'text' => 'Do you have friends?',   
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'svar4'
        ),
        array(
            'text' => 'Do you like going to the movies?',   
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'svar5'
            )
    );




    $step = isset($_POST['step']) ? $_POST['step'] : 0;

    if (isset($_POST['prev'])) {
        $step --;
    }


    if (isset($_POST['svar1'])) {
        $step++;
    }



    echo "<p><a href='/webutvikling/oblig2.php?reset=true'>Start på nytt</a></p>\n";
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spørreundersøkelse</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <style type="text/css">

        body {

            font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            background-color: #E0E0EB;
        }

        .wrapper {

            border: 1px solid black;
            text-indent: 10px;
            font-size: 1em;
            background: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        }
        </style>

        <h1>Spørreundersøkelse</h1>

        <form target="oblig2.php" method="post" >

            <input type="hidden" name="step" value="<?php echo $step ?>">

            <?php if (isset($questions[$step])) : ?>

                <p>Gjeldende steg: <?php echo $step +1 ?></p>

                <h3><?php echo $questions[$step]['text'] ?></h3>


                    <input type="<?=$questions[$step]['type']?>" autofocus name="<?= $questions[$step]['name']?>">


                <input type="submit" name="next" value="Send inn">

            <?php endif; ?>

            <br><br>

            <?php if ($step > 0) : ?>

            <input type="submit" name="prev" value="Forrige spørsmål">

            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if($step > 0):?>
                <input type="hidden" name="svar1" value="<?= isset($_POST['svar1']) ? $_POST['svar1'] : false   ?>" >
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if($step > 1):?>
                <input type="hidden" name="checkbox" value="<?= isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : false  ?>" >
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if($step > 2):?>
                <input type="hidden" name="svar3" value="<?= isset($_POST['svar3']) ? $_POST['svar3'] : false   ?>" >
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if($step > 3):?>
                <input type="hidden" name="svar4" value="<?= isset($_POST['svar4']) ? $_POST['svar4'] : false   ?>" >
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if($step > 4):?>
                <input type="hidden" name="svar5" value="<?= isset($_POST['svar5']) ? $_POST['svar5'] : false   ?>" >
            <?php endif;?>




        </form>




        <?= isset($_POST['svar1']) ? $_POST['svar1'] : false    ?> <br /> <br />
        <?= (isset($_POST['checkbox']) && $_POST['checkbox'] == 'on') ? 'Ja' : 'Nei'?> <br /> <br />
        <?= isset($_POST['svar3']) ? $_POST['svar3'] : false    ?> <br /> <br />
        <?= isset($_POST['svar4']) ? $_POST['svar4'] : false    ?> <br /> <br />
        <?= isset($_POST['svar5']) ? $_POST['svar5'] : false    ?> <br /> <br />


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` <- The way to go

Comment: Yeah.. I agree. I was thinking maybe questions array gets stored in $_SESSION and then the form can be generated with for loop and some heredoc syntax for longer html. PErhaps this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301203/php-session-array and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: this code is easily hackable. but i guess you are just new to programming and security is a later issue.

Comment: Dont hack my code, help me instead ;)